# How to filter data in FirebaseRecyclerOptions by spinner?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm using Firebase Database to show data in RecyclerView. Now I want to add a filter option by using an Android spinner. When I try to use different queries code doesn't work.
How can I use the spinner to show data for only 1 query and refresh this by changing the spinner item?
This code now works without a spinner click item.

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    query = reference.child("student");
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ModelPromocje> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ModelPromocje>()
                    .setQuery(query, ModelPromocje.class)
                    .build();
```

Spinner click item, when the position is 0 it should show all data

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0){
                query = reference.child("student");
            }
            else if (position == 1){
                query = reference.child("student").orderByChild("course").equalTo("Math");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user selects an option in the spinner, after you create the new `query` for the selected option, you'll need to update the adapter to use that new query.

You do that by creating a new `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` object with the new query, and then set that on the adapter by calling its `updateOptions`.

So something like this in your `onItemSelected`:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (position == 0){
        query = reference.child("student");
    }
    else if (position == 1){
        query = reference.child("student").orderByChild("course").equalTo("Math");
    }
    new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ModelPromocje>()
            .setQuery(query, ModelPromocje.class)
            .build();

    // Change options of adapter.
    mAdapter.updateOptions(newOptions)
}
```

There `mAdapter` is whatever the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is that you originally also passed your options to.

Comment: Thank you so much it works. Is there any way to refresh only the firebase data? Now when I switch options in spinner it goes to the top of my layout which is not very user friendly :)